# Laravel not returning S3 url

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-s3

Laravel 5.7. My default filesystem is set to S3:

**config/filesystems.php**

```php
'default' => env('FILESYSTEM_DRIVER', 's3'),
```

I am able to upload to S3 with this configuration. But when I use the [`url` method](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/filesystem#file-urls) to retrieve the full URL, I only get a relative URL back:

```php
return Storage::url($folder . '/' . $this->src);
```

returns `/image/filename.jpg`. What I expect is the full path to the S3 bucket + filename.

Comment: Did you set `'url'` in your S3 driver for  filesystems.php?

Comment: `Storage::url($this->src); ` try this.. in filesystem already refer to the bucket you already setup..

Comment: @senty You pointed me in the right direction. I had `AWS_URL=` (i.e. pointing to nothing) in my `.env` file. I just removed that key and it worked. If you want to write that as an answer I can mark it as correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `url` parameter in `filesystem.php` should be pointed to make `Storage::url($path)` to work.

As you pointed out (which I didn't realise), `AWS_URL` is present in .env, and it should be pointed.